# m600 pro seems cannot obtain control authority

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm developing matrice 600 pro osdk software.

now my program seems cannot obtain control authority.

I checked dji assistant's "sdk enabled" setting, and it was O.K.

After calling obtainCtrlAuthority(),

sending flight control commands cause no effect at all.

Subscription of barometer keeps succeeding.

My program had been working well , but after DJI support repair this problem has occurred.

Are there any settings I should confirm?

Any help will appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

flight mode switch must be in correct position (P mode for A3, N3, M600, M600 Pro and F mode for M100),please check it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This occurred under bridge and I used HORIZONTAL_VELOCITY flag. This doesn't work under weak GPS condition